# MAINFRAME: SORT in JCL to convert a dataset into CSV format

Tags: csv, sorting, mainframe, jcl

hope you are OK. I have a problem and I need your help, if possible.

I'm working with Mainframe JCL and I have a dataset with records; each record has different fixed columns separated by "~" (We use that since in the column NAME the names are separated by commas). I need to convert that dataset in a CSV file format, so it needs to be:
1) separated by comma 
2) with variable lenght instead of fix lenght 
3) I don't need all of the columns, just 4 of them (and in different order from original)
4) the first colum must be different 
5) If the name has a , (Ex: LAST NAME, NAME) use " "

This is an example of the input file:

```
ROLENAME~LID     ~NAME                  ~NONCNCL~ACCDATE ~SUSPEND
CARINQ  ~X       ~*** NOT FOUND ***     ~       ~        ~       
CARONL  ~AZBLCH  ~*** NOT FOUND ***     ~       ~        ~       
SOTHER  ~BZBWD4  ~SUAREZ, VICTOR        ~N      ~10/01/17~N      
CARONL  ~BZCJHS  ~CHURCH DAVID S        ~N      ~11/10/17~N      
CARONL  ~VZC2G1  ~*** NOT FOUND ***     ~       ~        ~       
CARONL  ~BZDKKF  ~PLAARDRTE ALLY        ~N      ~11/13/17~N      
SOTHER  ~HZDFGH  ~*** NOT FOUND ***     ~       ~        ~       
CARONL  ~JZFPOI  ~LOPEZ KAREN N         ~N      ~11/10/17~N      
CARONL  ~IZG0WZ  ~FOSHIL, RICHARD       ~N      ~11/13/17~N      
SOTHER  ~OZG3T2  ~CARLINE KECHUA        ~N      ~11/13/17~N      
CARONL  ~PZMMNB  ~BARELTINE, DUANE      ~N      ~11/13/17~N      
CARONL  ~PZNSWX  ~*** NOT FOUND ***     ~       ~        ~       
CARONL  ~RZPF5V  ~SLIMMORE JACK         ~N      ~10/12/17~N
```

This is an example of output file:

```
GMID,Name,Last Login Date,Role/Group 
X,*** NOT FOUND ***,,CARINQ
AZBLCH,*** NOT FOUND ***,,CARONL
BZBWD4,"SUAREZ, VICTOR",10/01/17,SOTHER
BZCJHS,CHURCH DAVID S,11/10/17,CARONL
VZC2G1,*** NOT FOUND ***,,CARONL
BZDKKF,PLAARDRTE ALLY,11/13/17,CARONL
HZDFGH,*** NOT FOUND ***,,SOTHER
JZFPOI,LOPEZ KAREN N,11/10/17,CARONL
IZG0WZ,"FOSHIL, RICHARD",11/13/17,CARONL
OZG3T2,CARLINE KECHUA,11/13/17,SOTHER
PZMMNB,"BARELTINE, DUANE",11/13/17,CARONL
PZNSWX,*** NOT FOUND ***,,CARONL
RZPF5V,SLIMMORE JACK,10/12/17,CARONL
```

I'm trying to use program SORT to use INREC PARSE and BUILD but I cannot get it completly, especially to make a field variable instead of fix lenght and to change the name of the columns, which in any case I could concatenate later if necessary, not big deal (I would like to avoid using EasyTrieve since I'm not that familiar with it).
Does anybody have any example of this? I looked for similar cases using SORT and I couldn't find any. I can create the report but only with fixed columns, I cannot find the way to do it variable lenght

I'm sorry for the long text but I wanted to be clear as much as possible.
Thank you very much in advance!
Have a good day/night!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not worried about the header, you can use:

```
OPTION COPY                              
INREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT,BUILD=(1,15,31,15,46,15,SQZ=(SHIFT=LEFT))),      
      IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT,FINDREP=(IN=C'~',OUT=C','))
```

I assumed the LRECL to be 80 and also assumed that you need only 3 columns starting from columns 1, 31 and 46 with 15 bytes each.

.

Comment: Thanks! That didn't work exactly as it is but it gave me some ideas to fix some errors.

Comment: @Jorge if the answer is useful, consider up-voting it a

Comment: I did....but it says that I don't have enough reputation to show that :(